# Calculating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \sin x}{x^2 - 2x + 10} dx $ via complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \sin x}{x^2 - 2x + 10} dx $$

So I am aware that this can be obtained by considering $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{z e^{iz}}{z^2 - 2z + 10} dz $ and then taking the imaginary part. But I want to know why the standard analysis here doesn't work.

So what I did was find the singularities of $z^2 - 2z + 10 = (z - (1 - 3i))(z - (1 + 3i)) $

Thus

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{z (e^{iz} - e^{-iz})}{2i(z^2 - 2z + 10)} dz = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{z e^{iz} }{2i(z^2 - 2z + 10)} dz - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{z e^{-iz} }{2i(z^2 - 2z + 10)} dz $$

Now $\int_{-R}^{R} \frac{z e^{iz} }{2i(z^2 - 2z + 10)} dz + \int_{C_R} \frac{z e^{iz} }{2i(z^2 - 2z + 10)} dz = 2\pi i Res(1+ 3i) = \lim_{z \to (1 + 3i)} 2\pi i \left (\frac{z e^{iz}(z - (1 + 3i)) }{(z - (1 - 3i))(z - (1 + 3i))} \right) =\pi \frac{(1+3i)e^{i-3}}{6i}$

So $$\int_{-R}^{R} \frac{z e^{iz} }{2i(z^2 - 2z + 10)} dz = \frac{\pi(1+3i)e^{i-3}}{6i}$$ since the half arc integral goes to $0$ by Jordan's Lemma.

Similarly $$\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{z e^{-iz} }{2i(z^2 - 2z + 10)} dz = -2pi Res(1-3i) = \frac{\pi (1-3i)e^{-i-3}}{6i}$$ (negative because the half loop that with base point $(-R,0)$ goes clockwise.

Therefore $$\frac{\pi(1+3i)e^{i-3}}{6i} - \frac{\pi (1-3i)e^{-i-3}}{6i}$$

According to Mathematica, this somehow reduces to $-\frac{\pi}{3e^3} (3 \cos(1) + \sin(1))$ which is the negative of what the actual answer is.

Comment: After "So", the integral should go from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, not from $-R$ to $R$. I can't see what you are aiming at after "Similarly".

Comment: No it is just a typo, it is going to take limit $R \to \infty$ eventually.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't enter this incorrectly into mathematica? Wolfram Alpha seems to confirm you are correct. [Direct Calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+-infinity+to+infinity+of+xsin%28x%29+%2F+%28x%5E2+-2x+%2B+10%29) vs [Your Answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%281%2B3i%29e%5E%7Bi-3%7D%7D%7B6i%7D+-+%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi+%281-3i%29e%5E%7B-i-3%7D%7D%7B6i%7D)
In both cases the answer is positive, so I'm not sure how you simplified to get a negative answer. Your calculations seem fine.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Probably. I had instant major doubts about my understanding when theory disagrees with their form of the answer.

Comment: @Hawk I wouldn't worry - looks to me like you did everything correctly, including choosing the right half planes and contours for the different exponentials. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

The contour integral needs only the upper half sphere, C. (You need to have the line on the real axis in the contour, since that will be the integrand you are supposed to calculate)
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
I=\int_{C}\frac{ze^{iz}}{(z-1)^2+3^2}dz
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Therefore, taking the residue of $z=1+3i$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
2\pi i Res(f,1+3i)=\frac{\pi(1/3+i)e^i}{e^3}
=\frac{\pi(1+3i)(\cos(1)+i\sin(1))}{3e^3}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $f$ is the integrand function.
The integral $I$ is the imaginary part of the above result, which gives
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\pi(\sin(1)+3\cos(1))}{3e^3}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

COMMENT: 
 In Jordan's lemma, if $f(z)$ is bounded when $z\rightarrow\infty$, and the intgrand takes the form, $f(z) e^{i \alpha z}$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
e^{i \alpha z}=e^{i\alpha Re(z)-\alpha Im(z)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
|e^{i \alpha z }|=e^{-\alpha Im(\alpha)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Therefore in the case $Re(\alpha)>0$ (the case is $\alpha=1>0$ in the question raised here), it converges to $0$ at $Im(z)\rightarrow\infty$ when $Im(z)>0$. This implies that you need to select the upper half circle as the contour.

I will add another method (but not using complex integral) to show that
$[\pi(\sin(1)+3\cos(1)]/(3e^3)$ is the correct answer.

First,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\sin ax}{x} dx\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\,\,\,\,\, (a>0) \\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\,\,\,\,\, (a<0) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

This can be derived by the following integration.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&I=\int^{\infty}_0e^{-\alpha x}\frac{\sin ax}{x}dx\,\,\,\,\,(\alpha>0)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Now take the derivative by $a$ of the above integral.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{dI}{da}=\int^{\infty}_0e^{-\alpha x}\cos ax\,dx=\frac{\alpha}
{\alpha^2+a^2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
This means that,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
I=\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{\alpha}+const.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Since when $a=0$, $I=0$, therefore const. above should be $0$. So, by taking the limit($\alpha\rightarrow 0$)

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&I=\int^{\infty}_0e^{-\alpha x}\frac{\sin ax}{x}dx
=\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\sin ax}{x}dx
=\left[\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{\alpha}\right]^{\infty}_0 \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\,\,\,\,\, (a>0) \\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\,\,\,\,\, (a<0) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

The integral is zero when $a=0$. Now substitute $a$ for $b+a$ and $b-a$ in the above equation where $b>a$.
Then you get
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\sin (b+a)x}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\,\,\,\,\, (a>0) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\sin (b-a)x}{x}dx =\frac{\pi}{2}\,\,\,\,\, (a>0) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
By adding these equations, you obtain,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\sin bx\,\cos ax}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\,\,\,\,\, (b>a>0) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
By subtracting on the other hand, you obtain,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\sin ax\,\cos bx}{x}dx=0\,\,\,\,\, (b>a>0) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
These relations however can be summarized as,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\sin bx\,\cos ax}{x}dx \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\,\,\,\,\, (b>a>0) \\
&=0\,\,\,\,\, (a>b>0) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Multiply $e^{-b\,c}\,(c>0)$ and take the integration by $b$.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\int^{\infty}_0e^{-b\,c}db\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\sin bx\,\cos ax}{x}dx \\
&=\int^{\infty}_ae^{-b\,c}db\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\sin bx\,\cos ax}{x}dx \\ 
&+\int^{a}_0e^{-b\,c}db\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\sin bx\,\cos ax}{x}dx \\
&=\int^{\infty}_a\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-b\,c}db=\frac{\pi}{2\,c}e^{-a\,c}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Now rewriting the integration as,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\int^{\infty}_0e^{-b\,c}db\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\sin bx\,\cos ax}{x}dx
=\int^{\infty}_0e^{-b\,c}\sin bx\,db\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\cos ax}{x}dx
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
and since,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\int^{\infty}_0e^{-b\,c}\sin bx\,db=\frac{x}{c^2+x^2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
it means that the relation obtained by the integral can be expressed as
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\cos ax}{c^2+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{2\,c}e^{-a\,c}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
When we differentiate the above by $a$, we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\int^{\infty}_0\frac{x\,\sin ax}{c^2+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\,e^{-a\,c}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Noticing that $x\,\sin ax/(x^2+c^2)$ and $\cos ax/(x^2+c^2)$ are even functions, 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{x\,\sin ax}{c^2+x^2}dx=\pi\,e^{-a\,c}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{\cos ax}{c^2+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{c}e^{-a\,c}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Now,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{\sin ax}{c^2+x^2}dx=0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
because the integrand is an odd function, and likewise
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{x\,\cos ax}{c^2+x^2}dx=0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

The integral raised here in the question is transformed by $y=x-1$, and using the above reults gives,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{(y+1)\,\sin (y+1)}{y^2+3^2}dy \\
&=\cos(1)\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{y\,\sin y}{y^2+3^2}dy
+\cos(1)\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{\sin y}{y^2+3^2}dy \\
&+\sin(1)\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{y\,\cos y}{y^2+3^2}dy
+\sin(1)\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{\cos y}{y^2+3^2}dy \\
&= \cos(1)\pi\,e^{-3}+\sin(1)\pi\,\frac{1}{3}e^{-3}
=\pi\,\frac{3\,\cos(1)+\sin(1)}{3\,e^3}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Comment: I am downvoting this because you did not read the full question.

Comment: Please see the comment I added.

Comment: I don't think the OP doubts the answer, they just did a calculation via Mathematica and thought they had it wrong. The OP's proof is fine though, so it was likely a programming error (either on OP 's part or Wolfram Devs' part)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Maybe I misunderstood what the question meant.